# Responsibility assignment matrix in Enterprise Architecture

Tags: enterprise-architect

[enter image description here][1]Will tell me whether The program enterprise architect can create a Responsibility assignment matrix Like program Visual Paradigm.

Comment: Maybe you explain what you are doing in VP to create that matrix and someone can answer it about EA.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, with the Relationship Matrix and overlays.

You can create an overlay to indicate the RACI value.

See the [help file](http://sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/12.1/building_models/matrix_overlays.html) for more info.

Comment: Will tell me whether.please

Comment: @Ghaderi I don't understand your question, sorry.

Comment: Please tell me how to do

Comment: @Ghaderi Please show some effort from your side. What did you try already, where did you get stuck? There's a reason why your question has been put on hold, and you're not making it any better.

Comment: I want for my project but I do not know my raci charts in software enterprise architect.
Relationship correlation matrix shows not what I want